# How can I find the complexity of this code segment?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity, complexity-theory, asymptotic-complexity

Here's the pseudocode of the code segment I'm talking about,

```
temp = 1

repeat
  for i = 1 to n
    temp = temp+1;

  n = n/2;
until n<=1
```

I know the outer loop (**repeat**) executes **n** times. What about the for loop? Can it be taken as a recursive call with n/2 ? How can I apply Master Theorem here?

Answer (score 4):

At the first iteration of the outer loop, the inner loop will be executed `n` times. At the next iteration, the inner loop will be executed `n/2` times, and so on...

So, we have the sum of geometric series `n + n/2 + n/4 + ...` i.e. `2*n` or `O(n)`.

Comment: @shekharsuman I think, your answer is incorrect. For 1 million elements your answer gives 20 millions iterations, my answer gives 2 million iterations. You can check the count of iterations manually for this problem.

Comment: @shekharsuman My assesment O(N) is correct for an infinite N, yes? For finite N it must be less. Your assesment is greater than O(N), so I think, your assesment is incorrect.

Comment: @shekharsuman I think, my answer is correct. Big-O is the upper bound of complexity. Your answer is correct also as any other answer that greater than O(N), but my answer is more precisely.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I assume that you are considering the addition to `temp` as the operation that has the cost you want to estimate. I refer to the initial value of `n` as `N` to distinguish between current and initial values. Moreover, I assume `n` is integral and that the step of the for loop is `1`.

As `n` is halved in each iteration, the outer loop executes `log N` (base 2) times. In each iteration, the inner for loop is doing `n` iterations:

`N` for the first iteration of the outer loop, `N/2` for the second, `N/(2*2)` on the third and so on. Generally speaking, on the ith iteration of the outer loop, the inner loop is run `N/(2^i)` times (assuming `i` is zero indexed, otherwise use `i - 1` in the exponent)

So mathematically, you have:

```
sum from 0 to log(N) - 1 of N/(2^i)
```

There is a different approach though:

You see an iterative algorithm, but it can be easily transformed into a recursive one (`floor` is doing integer division):

```
(defun recursive-outer (n temp)
  (if (<= n 1)
      temp
      (recursive (floor n 2) (inner n temp))))
```

This is easily translated into the master theorem equation

```
T(n) = 1 * T(n/2) + f(n)
```

with `f(n) = inner(n)` which is - trivially - in `O(n)`.

From here it should be easy to apply the master theorem.